# Using Sprayway glass cleaner as waterless wash?

Tags: paint, cleaning

I bought a four pack of Sprayway glass cleaner at Costco today, and it's amazing.  I tried it out on my car, and it makes it so shinny, it looks like it has just been waxed.

However, I want to make sure that this isn't bad for my paint in any way.  I'm sure there's some solvents in this cleaner that make it clean so well, so are they bad for my paint/clear coat?

Has anyone else had experience with this cleaner?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The main problem with using a cleaner like this is, while it removes all of the dirt and debris from the paint, it also removes any protection the paint might have on it, leaving it exposed to the elements and to UV rays which can cause faiding, oxidization, cracking, and pealing. Remember, glass is very resilliant stuff. It can withstand harsh chemicals (if needed). Glass cleaners in general will remove pretty much everything off of the surface of the glass, with any excess evaporating leaving the surface pristine. Your paint is not nearly as tough. Yes, it will clean it and leave it sparkling, but you are also taking any kind of protection it might have away. This will leave it open to the elements which will make it show its age much more quickly. You will do you car finish a much larger favor by cleaning it via normal means, then throwing some carnuba wax on top of it to provide it protection. This way the sparkle will not go away anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So it might be a good thing to do right before waxing it... but other than that, I should stick to normal soap and water?

Comment: @SpongeBob ... You are not doing your finish ***any*** good by doing this ... *None. What. So. Ever*. There are so many *good* ways to clean your car. This is not the way to do it.