# Is it bad to use household window/glass cleaners to clean the windshield?

Tags: cleaning, windshield

Is it bad to use household window/glass cleaners to clean the windshield? [This](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/22120/19474) answer for example recommends using household cleaners but doesn't mention any downsides. On the other hand, [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/15131/19474) post discusses the effect of using them on the paint not the glass itself.

Answer (score 2):

### [Don't use ammonia-based cleaners](http://www.incrediblydetailed.com/car-window-cleaning-tips-perfect-glass-windows-mirrors/)

- They will shorten the useful life of windshield wiper blades and rubber seals
- They dry out rubber and plastic
- They can damage window tint